Are mobile/chargeable battery chargers available?
When using battery chargers I understand they should never be used at home because
A) they give off toxic gases
B) they can explode if overcharged
How real is the threat of being affected by these toxic gases?  If I put it in my room which is ventilated wouldn’t that be safe enough?
And how likely is it to actually explode?
For those of us who don’t have garages etc I’m just wondering how likely it is that we could get harmed.  If it’s 1 in a million then I guess it’s very improbable etc and it’s safe to do.
At the same time, if a charger or maintainer was useable while not plugged and could be charged at home, then placed say in the cars boot and connected to the battery in the boot, that would be one way of charging it away from home.  Are there chargers that work like this or must they always be connected to a power source where they have to simultaneously charge the battery?
Thanks.

It depends on the type of battery. The older type has vented cell caps and release hydrogen. The newer type is sealed, but they have a pressure release system and can sometimes emit hydrogen.

Yes you can get portable rechargers as well as portable jump starters. Obviously the charging unit must have a greater capacity than the one being charged. FWIW when I recharge (with a mains unit) I place it inside the cabin and charge through the "cigar lighter" point.

tldr: get your battery in your bathroom, connect the charger and leave a window open. If an acidic/sulfuric smell develops, either the charger or the battery is bad, so power the charger off.

The toxic thing from the battery is a sulfuric acid vapors and fog. They are much more smelly than toxic so one cannot get poisoned without knowing. A sane battery will not give them off when properly charged.
The explosive thing from the battery is hydrogen. No smell, but usually goes with the sulfuric acid vapor. Also not an issue from a sane battery and charger. An open window keeps the concentration in the air low enough to be safe.

If a charger has to be used when not plugged in a power source, it has to carry the needed energy in itself. I.e. it has to contain some battery. Jump starters like this do exist, chargers - not much.
The other viable option that can charge a battery without (human-made) energy source could a solar charger.

The biggest danger is the hydrogen, which has nothing to do with the "sanity" of the charger. It's a small risk, but definitely a risk from sparks and naked flames.

@WeatherVane Hydrogen is released when the negative electrode of the lead-acid cell is overcharged. This could happen in a number of failure modes, e.g. overcharging the whole battery, overcharging a cell because of deep imbalance between the cells, overcharging the negative electrode because of deep imbalance between the negative and the positive electrode, etc, etc..., but when a depleted battery in a good condition is charged by a charger that has precise end-of-charge cut-off, only a minimal amount of hydrogen is released. 5A charger and an open window is a safe combination...

... even if all of these 5A go for producing hydrogen - the gas is impressively quick to diffuse out.

Hydrogen and oxygen are always released during healthy charging, unless the battery is sealed. That's what the charging process does.

@WeatherVane hell no, but see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead-acid_battery#Electrochemistry - hydrogen and oxygen are produced in unwanted, parasitic processes and are not related to the normal battery charge or discharge process.

Sorry, it's the simple electrolysis process of splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen. But when overcharging, you get more. With an unsealed battery, that's why you need to top up the cells with water, with a sealed battery it usually gets reabsorbed.

Yeah, so it's safe indoors until something goes wrong. Such as the sulphuric acid you mention, or someone lighting a cigarette next to a high concentration of hydrogen.
